# Rank customer Transactions per segments in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I have below **table** which has customer's transaction details.

| Tranactaction date | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1/27/2022 | 1 |
| 1/29/2022 | 1 |
| 2/27/2022 | 1 |
| 3/27/2022 | 1 |
| 3/29/2022 | 1 |
| 3/31/2022 | 1 |
| 4/2/2022 | 1 |
| 4/4/2022 | 1 |
| 4/6/2022 | 1 |

In this table consecutive transactions occurred in every two days considered as a segment.
For example, Transactions between **Jan 27th and Jan 29th** considered as segment 1  & Transactions between **Mar 29th and Apr 6th** considered as Segment 2.  I need to rank the transactions per segment with date order. If a transaction not fall under any segment by default the rank is 1.  Expected output is below.

| Segment Rank | Tranactaction date | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/27/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/29/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 2/27/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 3/27/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 3/29/2022 | 1 |
| 3 | 3/31/2022 | 1 |
| 4 | 4/2/2022 | 1 |
| 5 | 4/4/2022 | 1 |
| 6 | 4/6/2022 | 1 |

Can somebody guide how to achieve this in T-sql?

Comment: please do not post image. use formatted text instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [lag()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to check for change in `TransDate` that is within 2 days and groups together (as a segment). After that use `row_number()` to generate the required sequence

```
with 
cte as
(
    select *,
           g = case when datediff(day,
                                  lag(t.TransDate) over (order by t.TransDate),
                                  t.TransDate
                                  ) <= 2
                    then 0
                    else 1
                    end
    from   tbl t
),
cte2 as
(
    select *, grp = sum(g) over (order by TransDate)
    from cte
)
select *, row_number() over (partition by grp order by TransDate)
from   cte2
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c26f8da5b90fb8c56dd3b4cf2e1262f6)